# Issue with converting varchar to money back to varchar in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got a column in my database which contains a price, stored as a `varchar(10)`. The format that I need to pull it out as has a comma, but no decimal. So, if the price is `1500.00121`, it should come out as "1,500", with comma intact. So here is what I have so far:

```
CONVERT(varchar, CAST(p.Price1 AS money), 1)
```

This still has the decimal place to `".xx"` in it. How can I remove the decimal and trailing numbers while retaining the comma?

Comment: Actually, you should be storing these values as numeric types such as `decimal` or `money`.  And if the currency code is not guaranteed (and it usually isn't really guaranteed) then also store a currency code in a separate column.  And then do all currency formatting on the UI.

Comment: I have no control over the database or how the data is stored. Unfortunately, it's not my database. It's stored as a varchar so that's what I have to deal with :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not stored it in `Decimal(10,2)` datatype? It's much better than storing it in `VARCHAR` since you don't have extra casting to another datatype.

You can use `CAST` and `ROUND` function:

```
SELECT ROUND(CAST('1500.00121' AS DECIMAL(10,4)), 0, 1)
```

That's it. The `CAST` function converts datatype to another datatype. The `ROUND` function returns a numeric value, rounded to the specified length or precision.

The original syntax for `ROUND` is

```
ROUND ( numeric_expression , length [ ,function ] )
```

Where `Function` parameter is the type of operation to perform. `Function` must be *tinyint*, *smallint*, or *int*. When ***function is omitted*** or has a value of **0 (default), numeric_expression is rounded**. When a **value other than 0 is specified, numeric_expression is truncated**.

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/57b9d/8)

## [*ROUND (MSDN)*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

## [*Decimal (MSDN)*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)

Comment: I tried this, and it adds zeros to the end, and removes the comma, which is not what I need. So take "1500.00121". I need it to come out as "1,500".

Comment: so you need comma every thousand?

Comment: try something like this `SELECT (left(CONVERT(varchar, CAST('1500.00012' AS money), 1), Charindex('.', CONVERT(varchar, CAST('1500.00012' AS money), 1), 1) - 1 )) `

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will work

```
declare @q money = 1500.123

select parsename(convert(varchar,convert(money,@q), 1),2)
```

Comment: in your example, @q isn't going to be money, it's going to be a varchar. I need the comma intact, with no zero's at the end.

Answer (score 0):

No sql server on hand but Something like

```
Declare @correctlyTyped Money

Set @correctlyTyped = Convert(Money, SomeBadlyTypedField)

Select 
  Substring(@correctlyTyped,0,DataLength(@correctlyTyped) - CharIndex('.',@correctlyTyped ))
```

Convert it to money, then select everything up to the decimal point.

Note this is relying on the locale / collation of the data. In mainland Europe for instance, , is the decimal separator and . is the thousand separator.